# Where A=1 AND A=2 returns 0 row problem - (Short Mysql question)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `(id, Tag)` with the following values

```
(1, 17)
(1, 31)
(2, 17)
(3, 31)
```

When I query the following

```
"SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1 AND Tag=17 AND Tag=31"
```

I expected it to return (id)

```
(1)
```

But it doesn't. (returns 0 row)

What's wrong here?

Comment: `Tag` cannot be both `17` and `31` at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any particular row the tag can't be both 17 and 31. [You need](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

```
SELECT id 
FROM   table 
WHERE  Tag in (17, 31) 
GROUP  BY id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Tag) = 2
```

Comment: you forgot a space between Tag and in. Still +1 tough :)

Answer (score 2):

Machines are logic and do what you asked them to do... your expectations are wrong in this case.

Tag 17 AND tag 31 conditions according to [boolean math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) should be satisfied simultaneous to produce results.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a row with the value of Tag being 17 AND 31...at the same time. You probably want this (Also, `WHERE 1` is unneeded):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE Tag=17 OR Tag=31
```

EDIT: After reading some other answers, I decided to go crazy with this.

```
SELECT A.id 
FROM table A JOIN table B ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE A.Tag=17 AND B.Tag=31;
```

Comment: +2 For crazy join, -1 for confusing newbies :-)

Comment: Oops, doesn't return the correct result, sorry, see the difference between your code and @martin's

Comment: Wouldn't you want `WHERE A.Tag = 17 AND B.Tag = 31`? I haven't tested it, but wouldn't every record match the current conditions? Join `(2,17)` with itself `(2,17)` and both `A.Tag` and `B.Tag` are `IN (17,31)`.

Comment: +1 to Wiseguy. @josh: correct your query with Wiseguy's wise advice.

Comment: I have a feeling that in certain cases, this query (if corrected) would be faster than the 6-upvoted Martin's one.

Comment: Hilariously enough, I had this a a previous revision, but I had changed it to `IN` for some reason that I can't recall now.