# Where A IN () AND A IN () - developed MySQL question from Where A=1 AND A=2 returns 0 row

Tags: mysql

The original question is the following:

[Where A=1 AND A=2 returns 0 row problem - (Short Mysql question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889809/where-a-1-and-a-2-returns-0-row-problem-short-mysql-question)

Thanks for some helpful answers. (but soon I realized I may have over-simplified the problem)

Actually the real problem is the following:

```
Tag 1,2,3 - category A
Tag 4,5,6 - category B
Tag 7,8,9 - category C
```

I want to achieve "OR condition" for the same category but "AND condition" for different category.
So I may want to return something like

```
-- I want id with Tag 1,4 or 1,2,4 but not 4
SELECT id FROM table WHERE Tag IN (1,2) AND Tag (4)

-- Tag 1,4 or 1,5 but not 1
SELECT id FROM table WHERE Tag IN (1) AND Tag (4,5)

-- Only Tag 1,4,9
SELECT id FROM table WHERE Tag IN (1) AND Tag (4) AND Tag (9)
```

I am trying to figure out from the answers, but any quick guide would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you want to return ids that are tagged over at least 2 different categroies, try this:

```
Select id from Table 
WHERE tag_category in (A,B,C) 
Group by id 
Having count(distinct tag_category) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want those categories that have been tagged with given tag ids (only those that are tagged with ALL the given tag ids):

```
Select id from Table
WHERE tag in (A,B,C)
Group by id
Having count(id)>=3
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a 'must have' condition, but you want to select only those that are in your optional list.

Try this:

```
SELECT id from Table 
WHERE Tag IN (1,2)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table WHERE Tag=4)
```

It's not clear what your source data looks like. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as my answer as to your previous question.

The difference being in the `HAVING` clause. It now allocates a different number for each tag group. So `id in (1,2)` is given the number `1`. The `else` clause applies to tag number `4` and these tags are given the group number `2`. Then it counts the number of different tag group numbers for that `id` and only returns `id`s which have a count of 2 meaning that both tag groups were present.

```
SELECT id 
FROM   table 
WHERE  Tag in (1,2,4) 
GROUP  BY id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Tag in (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 2
```

Comment: The other 2 queries looks simpler for dynamically generated codes. (Having query gotta be generated as the category grows) But still thanks. you all inspired me to finish off my codes. :)

Comment: @user - The other two that you have commented on as being helpful don't look like they will work to me!